# correlation that is less sensitive to neighboring class changes

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, spearman-rho

I am calculating the correlation between the scores a radiologist attributes to an MRI image (discrete 0,1,2,3), against the continuous quantification of disease (continuous between 0 and 1). I see a lot of cases where I ask radiologist why he has attributed for example score 1 and he says he has been too much sensitive and if he score it today, he will give it a 0.
I'm wondering how can I calculate the correlation in a way that it's not sensitive to these neighboring class changes, but penalizes farther class changes more.
I hope that is clear.

Comment: Spearman's rho, which you are already using, will be less sensitive to small differences in rank than large ones. Do you want a measure that won't be sensitive to a difference of 1 at all? I don't know of one, you might have to invent it, but I would advise against using it.

Comment: It sounds like you want a correlation measure that considers the possible dependence between measurements when the doctors disagree with how they did their previous assessments. Is that correct?